# MSP430F5438A: How can I see the flash memory content in CCS?

Tags: memory, flash

I have to establish a file transfer mode between C# and CCS.
To make sure the text files has transferred properly, after sending a file I read it from C# to compare with the origin.

I need to look at the flash memory content all the time for these reasons:

1. I get different results of writing to specific memory segments, for instance: if I start writing at 0x20000, **some** characters distord, but if I start at 0x20008, everything works OK then, 0x20016 half OK half garbage, etc..
2. Even with the Non-problems mode (0x20008) just the transferring the **first** file works fine, if I send another file and try to read it then, **all** I get is just garbage.

This photo if anyone would like to see the writing/reading procedure code:

[image]

Comment: I think you can just use the memory browser in CCS.  Run your program then load the memory browser "view->memory browser".  You should be able to type in the address you want hit enter and it will show you the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the distortion you see may be because you don't erase the flash before programming it again.

You are using the WRITE bit but you must have a piece of code that uses ERASE bit set to erase the block.

With flash you must erase everything as a block before writing. This is the number one issue I see when helping customers do over the air updates and firmware updates.

The other reason is that the data didn't arrive properly for whatever reason.

Comment: I guess I do erase the block but not sure if it is the right way, in main I have this:
FCTL1 = FWKEY+ERASE;      
*(unsigned int *)Flash_ptr = 0;

Comment: if I do the erasing operation after clearing the lock bit and before setting the WRT bit, I still have the same problem even worse, ALL THE TIME GARBAGE :)

Comment: Post the code you have now so we can see. You need to erase, then write.

Comment: Gustavo, How I am supposed to erase the segment? I guess I don't erase anything, cuz I tried just to erase and not to write anything but nothing has been deleted!
Here is the steps: Firstly, before main:
char * Flash_ptr = (char *) 0x30000;
and then I implement the deletion in main (so that the deletion would be executed just once):
FCTL1 = FWKEY+ERASE;                      
*(unsigned int *)Flash_ptr = 0;        
while(!(WAIT & FCTL3));
am I missing something?

Comment: That looks good but make sure the pointer address is good. Then check in the memory window and all the bytes should be at 0xFF in the segment that was erased.

Comment: I did some fixes, but now the only problem is that working with 0x20000 (Block B) still some distorted chars but in Info Blocks everything works fine.
why i'm saying that? because on the left of this line:
char * Flash_ptr = (char *) 0x20000;
was a warning saying: #173-D Invalid type conversion
replacing it with:
char * Flash_ptr = (char *) 0x1800;
then the warning disappeared and everything works good with non-distortions

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221856/173-d-invalid-type-conversion)
is the problem!